# Maven build all sub-modules even with a profile

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have following segment in the parent pom.xml file

```
<groupId>my.group</groupId>
<artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
    <module>../A</module>
    <module>../B</module>
</modules>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>P1</id>
        <modules>
            <module>../B</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
<profiles>
```

When i try to execute the `compile goal` of this pom file with the `profile P1` (In IDEA 14 Maven Projects window) it will **compile the both module A and B**.

But if I remove the modules segment, It will compile only the module B. (as mention in the profile)

```
<modules>
    <module>../A</module>
    <module>../B</module>
</modules>
```

But i want to keep the modules tag as it is and *use profile to compile only the module B*. Is there any solution to overcome this issue.

Comment: Why not using `mvn -pl moduleB clean package` ? Never use profiles include/exclude modules: http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2013/11/09/why-is-it-bad-to-activate-slash-deactive-modules-by-profiles-in-maven/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a separate profile for building both module A and B. You can have this profile active by default. So that will not change the existing behavior.

```
<groupId>my.group</groupId>
<artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>P1</id>
        <modules>
            <module>../B</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>Everything</id>
        <modules>
            <module>../A</module>
            <module>../B</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
<profiles>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I use the modules tag to define all the modules because of it will detect by the IDEA and load those modules to the 'Project Tree'. So if I remove that one IDE project Tree will not get populated. According to the approach you have suggested If i unselected the 'Everything' profile in the IDEA maven window and select only the P1 (to compile only the B) IDEA will automatically update the Project Tree (Remove module A and Keep only the B) [Bottom line : I need to have both module A and B in the project tree regardless of the selected profile]